# Does every thing need a hechsher?

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

Do objects used in food preparation and foods that have no or little chance of being not kosher really need a hechsher?

Please cite sources, if you can.

Comment: I don't understand your question. No not everything needs a hechsher. Some things do some things don't. Are you looking for a complete list?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think he's looking for a yes or no answer with an explanation, not a list.

Comment: @SethJ So if I provide one example of a food that doesn't need a hechsher and one example of a food that does need a hechsher that will completely and satisfactorily answer the question?

Comment: I'd think that an example of a commonly used food that doesn't need one and an explanation contrasting it to foods that might be in the same category in some people's minds but do require one, would probably work wonders. I happen to know who user2449 is and we were discussing aspartame.

Comment: @SethJ Why the same category?

Comment: @DoubleAA, just a suggestion. Comparing [plastic bags](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6353/5) to meat might be a "duh" kind of answer, unless it's explained more thoroughly than, "duh, plastic is plastic and meat is meat."

Comment: http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/milk_and_honey.php

Comment: By the way, user2449, welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. You might also think about adopting a new user name, unless you're particularly fond of the number 2449! :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one agency's list of what doesn't need a hechsher
http://www.star-k.org/cons-appr-no-need.htm

this is one answer about why some apparently hechsher free items might need a hechsher
http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/144,2095417/Why-do-supervision-agencies-supervise-products-that-do-not-need-a-hechsher.html

this is about things that get into unsupervised food that don't appear on ingredients labels
http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/529218/jewish/Do-packaged-frozen-vegetables-require-kosher-certification.htm

and this article also deals with actual problematic ingredients
http://www.aish.com/jl/m/mm/Isnt_Water_Kosher.html

this one discusses relying on ingredients lists
http://www.ok.org/Content.asp?ID=116

I know that the OU put out an article about processing and the mashgiach's familiarity with more than just superficial ingredients but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

> Rabbi Yitzchak Abadi, formerly a posek in Lakewood, and currently a
>   Rosh Kollel in Jerusalem, as well as founder of
>   http://www.kashrut.org/. He is of the opinion that Jews should
>   continue in the ways of the Tanaiim in figuring out for themselves
>   whether a food product is kosher or not. Hechsherim are **mostly**
>   superfluous; it's sufficient to read the ingredients intelligently. He
>   uses his authority to bravely declare that, for example, one may eat a
>   tuna sandwich at any Subway chain, whether under kosher supervision or
>   not, if one follows some simple guidelines. See here, here, and here.
>   In fact, do yourself a favor and browse this website a bit. It's an
>   eye opening experience for most frum Jews whose minds have been
>   cluttered by too many kashruth organizations' acronyms.

http://dovbear.blogspot.com/2007/08/you-dont-have-to-be-apikorus-to-heart.html

Comment: Though even he says some things need hechshers

Comment: Isn't he basically the only Orthodox rabbi who holds this way? Don't all other poskim rule that all processed foods need a hechsher? On what basis could one choose to hold by the one rabbi who goes against the virtual unanimity of all other rabbis?

Comment: This site's policy isn't to Pasken Halacha Lemaaseh. It's to bring opinions and sources **regardless** of whether we agree or not and that's exactly what I did.

Comment: @Shmuel I disagree. Sometimes he is more strict and sometimes he is more lenient. Any posek who does not have that quality is not trustworthy IMO.

Comment: @DoubleAA did you ever see his Pesakim in Even HaEzer? Very, very strict.

Comment: @Kordovero On the basis of asking your rabbi if he holds like him. That is the only way most Jews should be making halachic decisions anyway.

Comment: Where is his kollel in Jerusalem?